# End program after breaking from loop

Tags: c++11

```
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter number and unit: ";
    cin >> number;
    cin >> unit;

    if (unit == "in")
    {
        result = 2.54f * number;
        cout << number << " Inches are " << result << " centimeters!" << endl;
    }
    else if (unit == "ft")
    {
        result = 0.3f * number;
        cout << number << " Feet are " << result << " meters!" << endl;
    }
    else if (unit == "yd")
    {
        result = 0.9f * number;
        cout << number << " Yards are " << result << " meters!" << endl;
    }
    else if (unit == "mi")
    {
        result = 1.6f * number;
        cout << number << " Miles are " << result << " kilometers!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {   
        cout << "\tINVALID!!!\n...the program will now exit...\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin >> unit;
        cin >> number;
        break;
    }
}

cout << "Thank you for using English to Metric!\n" << endl;

return 0;}
```

What am I missing in order to get the last cout and exit the program without having to input anything after break?

Comment: notice the first line "while (1) { cout << "Enter number and unit: "; cin >> number; cin >> unit;".... the editor wont let me post if I include the line in the code text. 

edit:  Someone fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Might have just needed a sentence or two before the code to make it work. I didn't even know it doesn't allow a submission like that.

Comment: Now we know :) Thanks

Comment: So what do you mean by needing to input something after the break? Does it not immediately exit the loop, print out the last line, and exit the program? Other than the `cin`s after printing "INVALID..." it shouldn't be requesting any input. I might be missing something too if it's not doing that.

Comment: At least in my compiler I have to input something before it prints "Thank you for using English to Metric!\n". For example say I enter 'L' it prints out the invalid message but then I have to input something (anything) right after to see the 'Thank you' message.

Comment: Is this input related to the lines `cin >> unit;` and `cin >> number;` after `cout << "\tINVALID!!!\n...the program will now exit...\n";`? If that's what you're talking about, you can safely get rid of those lines because you're not using those values anymore anyway, and it will print out "Invalid ..." and "Thank you ..." right after.

Comment: No, those inputs are for the cin.clear() function. If I didn't use the function and the cin for each variable I would get an infinite loop and the variables would hold the 'invalid' value entered.

Comment: OOOOOOh! Now that I think about it the code is waiting for the second variable to be entered. That is why is asking me to put something in before it exits.


edit: you were right. Since I used cin for each variable is expecting the second input. I had to talk it over to get it. Thank you jonhopkins

Comment: I don't use C++ very often so maybe I'm just misunderstanding, but why are you using `cin.clear()` at all anyway? It clears error flags within the `cin` object, but the only "error" is that you didn't get a recognized unit or number, right? And I don't get what you mean by "inputs for the cin.clear() function"..

Comment: If i dont use the cin.clear(); i would run into an infinite loop. The value of the variables would hold the invalid input and then the loop would start again holding that erroneous value and input it again by itself (i am not sure why this happens). cin.clear(); helps to prevent that from happening. I added Cin >> number and value because I thought I needed to ( based on an example i read  but in reality I didnt have to).

Comment: But doesn't the `break` get you out of the loop? I don't know... I might try this later today just because it's going to bug me, but this is getting away from the question, so I'm going to stop asking questions haha. But as a final note, look into `cin.ignore()`. It will clear out anything inside the buffer so you shouldn't get stuck with wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

The `break`  in the `else` clause will exit the loop, but immediately before it you perform

```
cin.clear();
cin >> unit;
cin >> number;
break;
```

The `cin >>`s are why the program is waiting for additional input.

Without them, the `cin.clear()` is unnecessary, unless you plan to do additional `cin` operations later.

```
    else
    {
        std::cin.clear();  // optional
        break;
    }
}  // end while
std::cout << "Thank you\n";
```

Will work.